# Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times. in react

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have checked All the stack overflow questions. I can't solve this problem I am new to jest
**UNIT TEST**

```
const testValues = {
    Promo_Code: "FOO",
    onSubmit: jest.fn()
  };

it("Submit works", () => {
    const component = shallow(
        <Create.WrappedComponent {...testValues} />
    );
    component.find("#submitButton").simulate("submit");
    expect(testValues.onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(testValues.onSubmit).toBeCalledWith({
        username: testValues.username,
        password: testValues.password
    });
});
```

Error: - **Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times.**

Answer (score 0):

Try the below approach,

```
component.find('form').simulate('submit', { preventDefault () {} });
```

[or]

```
component.find('form').props().onSubmit();
```